# XpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence throws XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer, xamlparseexception

I have to import an `.xlsx` file into my WPF application and view it. I convert the document to .`xps` and then loading. After that I call `GetFixedDocumentSequence()` and there I get this Exception

> XamlParseException:
>
> {"UnicodeString property does not contain enough characters to
>   correspond to the contents of Indices property."}.

here is my code:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    string xpsPath = ViewDocumentViewer("D:\\test.xlsx");
    DisplayXPSFile(xpsPath);
}

private string ViewDocumentViewer(string path)
{
    try
    {
        string xpsPath;
        var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excelApp.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
        xpsPath = ExportXPS(excelWorkbook, path);
        excelWorkbook.Close(false, null, null);
        excelApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        excelApp = null;

        return xpsPath;
    }
    catch
    { 
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

string ExportXPS(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook, string path)
{
    string xpsFileName;
    xpsFileName = (new DirectoryInfo(path)).FullName;
    xpsFileName = xpsFileName.Replace(new FileInfo(path).Extension, "") + ".xps";
    excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypeXPS,
    Filename: xpsFileName,
    OpenAfterPublish: false);

    return xpsFileName;
}

void DisplayXPSFile(string xpsFileName)
{
    XpsDocument xpsPackage = new XpsDocument(xpsFileName, FileAccess.Read, CompressionOption.NotCompressed);
    FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = xpsPackage.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    DocView.Document = fixedDocumentSequence;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks there was something wrong with the Excel conversion to XPS.
That's usually associated with a Glyphs or Font problem.
You can open your XPS file (I use this extension on Visual Studio: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b?SRC=VSIDE) to see where the problem is coming from. Navigate to the page generating the error and find the Glyphs containing the problem.

```
<Canvas Clip="F 1 M137.710006714,208.58001709 L476.861022949,208.58001709 L476.861022949,208.58001709 L476.861022949,219.83001709 L476.861022949,219.83001709 L137.710006714,219.83001709 Z">
    <Glyphs OriginX="0" OriginY="0" UnicodeString="D" Indices=",55.6" Fill="#FF000000" FontRenderingEmSize="1" FontUri="/Resources/076a5115-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.odttf" RenderTransform="8.949999809,0,0,8.949999809,185.458496094,218.330078125" />
</Canvas>
```

You can also find more documentation regarding this ar MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748985.aspx

Since use are using Excel Interop to generate the XPS you will have almost no control of the conversion procedure, so I would suggest to review the fonts used on the Excel document. 
Maybe there's some issue with the fonts being used.

Regards